# Deleting Specific Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to delete duplicate records that do not contain a specific status.

Here is my code:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[test] 
WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT MAX(ID) 
                  FROM [dbo].[test] 
                  GROUP BY [UserID] ) 
AND Status <> 'D'
```

I need to delete all duplicate records except the records that contain the status 'D'. The error that it is giving me is incorrect syntax.

The ultimate problem is that I am inserting data from two tables. One table, Support, inserts information that needs to update the master table, Data. The other table, Identity, provides the user database for the master table. If the status from the support table reads 'D' for Disable, I need to keep both records in the master table.

Comment: why is condition "And status <> 'D' " outside bracket?

Comment: Kept getting syntax errors.

Comment: Try mine and @GordonLinoff solution.

Comment: so it worked. Thanks for accepting answer.

Comment: I don't see have changing the order fixed it.  That query looks valid.  Maybe you have a funky '.  Where does it say the error is.

Comment: @Paparazzi just got lucky i think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[test] 
WHERE  Status <> 'D' AND  ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM [dbo].[test] 
GROUP BY [UserID])
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between yours and the OP query other than the order?

Comment: @bjones to be very honest i just moved condition on top. I dont have anything to test now so really not sure if it will work or not

Comment: Both queries work the same. That's why I asked what the difference was. I don't know what difference your query made to accept it as the answer. Like Paparazzi said, maybe it was a misplaced ' somewhere.

Comment: @bjones yes may be i was lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks ok.  Here is an alternative method:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, max(id) over (partition by userid) as maxid
      from dbo.test
     )
delete from todelete
    where id < maxid and status <> 'D';
```

Your question mentions different tables, but this query only mentions one table.  I could understand a "column not found" error, but your syntax looks ok.